# Ajax, Can't load xml data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xml

While I am trying to load my xml data trough ajax it just not working..
I can't see the data display..

```
var xmlHttp = createXMLHttpReq();    
function createXMLHttpReq() {
    var xmlHttp;
    try {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsogt.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            alert("Not supported for your browser");
        }
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}

function exam(id) {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 0 || xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        xmlHttp.open("GET", "examajax.php?id=" + id, true);
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
        xmlHttp.send();
    } else {
        setTimeOut(exam(), 1000);
    }
}

function handleResponse() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
        data = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.firstChild.data;
        document.getElementById("mainform").innerHTML = data;
    }
}
```

examajax.php file :

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type : text/xml");
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>';
    echo '<response>';
        $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? intval($_GET['id']) : 0;
        $p = isset($_GET['s_p']) ? intval($_GET['s_p']) : 1;
        $loadAll = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE `testid` = $id");
        $ofp = mysql_num_rows($loadAll);
        $selected = (isset($_GET['sel']) && is_numeric($_GET['sel']) && $_GET['sel'] <= $ofp && $_GET['sel'] >= 1) ? $_SESSION['sel'.$p] = intval($_GET['sel']) : null;
        $loadQuestion = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE `testid` = $id && `pos` = $p ORDER BY -`id` DESC LIMIT 1");
        while ($question = mysql_fetch_array($loadQuestion)) {
            ?>
            שאלה <?php echo $p; ?>/<?php echo $ofp; ?>
            <?php echo $question['name']; ?>
            <input type="radio" onclick="select(1,<?php echo $p; ?>)" value="<?php echo $question['op1']; ?>" />
            <input type="radio" onclick="select(2,<?php echo $p; ?>)" value="<?php echo $question['op2']; ?>" />
            <input type="radio" onclick="select(3,<?php echo $p; ?>)" value="<?php echo $question['op3']; ?>" />
            <input type="radio" onclick="select(4,<?php echo $p; ?>)" value="<?php echo $question['op4']; ?>" />
            <input type="radio" onclick="select(5,<?php echo $p; ?>)" value="<?php echo $question['op5']; ?>" />
            <?php
        }
    echo '</response';
?>
```

If i'm changing the innerHTML to some string instead of data it will display the string .. but for some reason it doesn't load the xml data.. help please?

Comment: This could fail at many places, you will need to do some more testing and provide information : do you see anything happening in the console ? Do you see the request in the network panel ? Does it look correct ?

Comment: you might want to change echo '</response' to echo '</response>'

Comment: i changed it, but still nothing display..

Comment: Bartdude is right, this can fail for many reasons. For instance, you define functions, but don't call them. Maybe your console shows an error but we have no idea. Besides, you set the "jQuery" tag, why not use it? Your code would become `$.get("examajax.php").success( function(data){ $("#mainform").html(data) } )`

Comment: Also, you declare `var xmlHttp` twice, in two different scopes.

Comment: Well, i'm still at the begging of learning ajax. does i have any mistakes in my code?

Comment: xmlhttp is the problem, i needed to type xmlHttp, my bad.. but the code only run when its on a server.. i cant run it from my personal pc.. then i get an "undefinded" error

Comment: Which part? The PHP requires a web server to execute.